# Disable Wired When Wireless is UP

Tags: networking, wireless

My Laptop has Wired and wireless connection capabilities.
I want to disable my Wired connection when my wireless is up and running ?
How can i proceed ?
I used nmcli tool to establish my connection.

nmcli con up id 
nmcli con up id

Currently i have  Wired and Wireless up and running 
I also try to use 
nmcli con down id  but unsucess

Thanks

Comment: Not the answer you're looking for, I'm sure... but I just unplug the Ethernet cable.  That shuts down the wired connection very effectively.

Answer (score 2):

A raw solution could be to create an if-up script in /etc/network/if-up.d/, something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$IFACE" = "wlan0" ]; then
  ifconfig eth0 down
fi
```

Remeber to give it execution permissions.

Comment: And something in `/etc/network/if-down.d/` to counter.