# Auto-switching between wired and wireless connections?

Tags: networking

At home I have a wired (ethernet via USB-C dock) network connection at my desk.  I also have a number of Unifi Access Points around the place for when I'm working in another room.

In my head, I would expect Ubuntu to disable/switch off WiFi when it detects a physical connection, and turn it on again when that physical connection is removed however, it seems to leave both interfaces running with IP Addresses assigned.

All the posts I've found on here by searching (listed below) are years old or use Network Manager, whereas I'm pretty sure I'm using systemd-networkd.

It's not a massive problem, as the connection works regardless and it appears to favour the wired option, I'm just concerned that if the routes go wonky for some reason (I run a lot of VM's and containers on my laptop that are respawned on a regular basis) I'll loose connectivity.

**Posts I've looked at already**

- [automatic switch between the Wifi and ethernet in Linux using command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481165/automatic-switch-between-the-wifi-and-ethernet-in-linux-using-command-line) (8 years old)
- [How to switch from wireless to wired connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1110579/how-to-switch-from-wireless-to-wired-connection) (4 years old)
- [Both wired and wireless connected; how do they interact?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1400730/both-wired-and-wireless-connected-how-do-they-interact) (1 year ago, but not really what I'm asking)
- [Disable Wired When Wireless is UP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20301/disable-wired-when-wireless-is-up) (right question, but 12 years old!)
- [Turn off WiFi when connected to Thunderbolt dock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/934450/turn-off-wifi-when-connected-to-thunderbolt-dock) (possibly an answer, but uses NetworkManager rather than systemd-networkd, and 5 years old)
- [Frequent switches between Ethernet and Wifi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1393239/frequent-switches-between-ethernet-and-wifi) (just over a year old, but also relies on network manager)

** My System **

Running Ubuntu Desktop:

```
cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS"
```

```
lspci 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 11th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 01)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] (rev 01)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP Dynamic Tuning Processor Participant (rev 01)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation GNA Scoring Accelerator module (rev 01)
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Tigerlake Telemetry Aggregator Driver (rev 01)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller (rev 01)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 20)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Shared SRAM (rev 20)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 (rev 20)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 20)
00:15.3 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #3 (rev 20)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Management Engine Interface (rev 20)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a0bb (rev 20)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev 20)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP LPC Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SMBus Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SPI Controller (rev 20)
01:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller 980
```

Happy to provide more system information etc. if needed.

Comment: I've written a bash script to help with this: `https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic` It watches the connection, and when the connection drops, does a user-specified thing to try to reconnect. You could adapt  it for your use.

Comment: @guiverc - I've updated it.  I'm running Ubuntu Desktop.